# Echo outputting results in erratic order in BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos

Word of warning: I'm relatively new to BASH scripting, so any advice on my hacky scripting is appreciated.

I have a strange issue, in my code I've collected a bunch of error strings from a file in one array, and a second array stores the count of the errors in the same index (I did this given the lack of 2D arrays, and didn't really want to approach building a matrix).

When outputting the code I use this line:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#NAME_ARRAY[@]}; i++)); do
   echo "Error: ${NAME_ARRAY[$i]} x ${COUNT_ARRAY[$i]}"
done
```

In this case I'm testing with two separate files, if I run it on file one I get this output:

> Error: Exception: unknown/unregistered file format :  x 72982

That's cool, works fine and exactly as expected. I know there is only one error ("Exception: unknown/unregistered file format : ") in the huge log file, and that it appears 72982 times.

But in my other case I get this result:

> x 66964xception: Some kind of disk I/O error occurred

Here's where I'm utterly lost. If I print out ${NAME_ARRAY[$i]} individually, I get "Some kind of disk I/O error occurred" perfectly fine. Similarly if I print out ${COUNT_ARRAY[$i]} by itself I get "66964"...but when I put them both in a string, the COUNT_ARRAY number gets thrown into the start of my string and overrides the "Error: " part.

Figuring I could be a little smart and a lot hacky, I decided to do this:

```
echo -n "Error: ${NAME_ARRAY[$i]}"
echo " x ${COUNT_ARRAY[$i]}"
```

My amateur mind thought this would separate the two outputs (in case of any sort of threading/priority issues) but alas, I still get the exact same result.

Am I missing something extraordinarily obvious? Or are my echos doing something weird.

I also just tested using printf instead of echo and the same thing happens. Could there be some sort of character encoding issue that's stuffing up when printing to console?

Comment: You might want to check your input file for any unicode characters or newline oddities. A quick `file` run might show something. A peek with a hex editor couldn't hurt, either.

Comment: Well, the two files have these outputs:

File 1: ASCII English text, with very long lines

File 2: ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: looks like a carriage return snuck in; maybe output your matches piped through `od -c` to confirm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Some kind of disk I/O error occurred" message is very likely to contain a `\r` character at the end. This resets the cursor to the beginning of the current line, causing the " x 66964" which is output next to overwrite the beginning of the line. To fix it, you need to strip out the carriage return when you read it into $NAME_ARRAY, e.g. by piping through `tr -d '\r'`.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what the problem was. Thanks!